# Testing controllers with nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, controller, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I'm new to Ruby and I'm slowly making progress. I've just gotten to testing.

Please note that I'm not yet using any testing framework, merely what rails (5.2.3) provides out of the box.

I have authors who have many books `has_many :books` and books that belong to authors `belongs_to :author`.

These are my fixtures:

books.yml

```
tmaas:
  name: The Mysterious Affair at Styles
  published: 1920
  author_id: agatha_c

tgow:
  name: The Grapes of Wrath
  published: 1939
  author_id: john_s
```

authors.yml

```
agatha_c:
  name: Agatha Christie

john_s:
  name: John Steinbeck
```

I ran

```
rails test test/controllers/books_controller_test.rb
```

but I'm getting errors for these tests:

```
BooksControllerTest#test_should_update_book
BooksControllerTest#test_should_show_book
BooksControllerTest#test_should_get_edit
BooksControllerTest#test_should_destroy_book
```

The error is always the same, it can't find the book.

```
Error:
BooksControllerTest#test_should_destroy_book:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Book with 'id'=445166326 [WHERE "books"."author_id" = ?]
    app/controllers/books_controller.rb:72:in `set_book'
    test/controllers/books_controller_test.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in <class:BooksControllerTest>'
    test/controllers/books_controller_test.rb:46:in `block in <class:BooksControllerTest>'
```

The problem comes from calling:

```
author_book_url id: books(:tmaas).id, author_id: @author.id
```

or

```
edit_author_book_url id: books(:tmaas).id, author_id: @author.id
```

```
test "should destroy book" do
    assert_difference('Book.count', -1) do
      delete author_book_url id: books(:tmaas).id, author_id: @author.id
    end

    assert_redirected_to author_books_url(@author)
  end
```

`@author` is set in `setup`

```
setup do
    @author = authors(:agatha_c)
  end
```

The set_book function in the controller:

```
def set_book
      @book = @author.books.find(params[:id])
    end
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what made my tests pass:

First, you should correct your `books.yml` file to:

```
tmaas:
  title: The Mysterious Affair at Styles
  published: 1920
  author: agatha_c

tgow:
  title: The Grapes of Wrath
  published: 1939
  author: john_s
```

This are my tests for the `book_controller` actions:

1. Test for create action:

```
  test "should create book" do
    assert_difference('Book.count') do
      post author_books_url(@book.author), params: { book: { 
        author_id: @book.author_id, 
        title: @book.title,
        published: @book.published 
      }}
    end

    assert_redirected_to author_book_url(Book.last.author, Book.last)
  end
```

2. Test for update action:

```
  test "should update book" do
    patch author_book_url(@book.author, @book), params: { book: { 
      author_id: @book.author_id, 
      title: @book.title,
      published: @book.published 
    } }
    assert_redirected_to author_book_url(@book.author, @book)
  end
```

3. Test for destroy action:

```
  test "should destroy book" do
    assert_difference('Book.count', -1) do
      delete author_book_url(@book.author, @book)
    end

    assert_redirected_to author_books_url(@book.author)
  end
```

Check the officials Rails guides, might be helpful: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#functional-tests-for-your-controllers

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're really saving me here! I found that whether I would pass \@book.author, \@book.author_id or \@book.author.id to author_book_url, for example id: \@book.id, author_id: \@book.author.id, the tests would pass. This kind of erratic behavior slightly put me off.

Comment: Really glad to help. For me, whenever I get stuck, I first try to check the official guides and then try some other resource. At this case, you might want to read this: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects Hope it will be helpful for you.